# Automorphism groups of symmetric cones

Tags: lie-groups, symmetric-spaces, jordan-algebras

Indecomposable symmetric cones fall into five classes. The automorphism group of any symmetric cone $C$ is a real Lie group $Aut(C)$. What is the associated class of Lie groups $Aut(C)$ for each of the five classes of indecomposable symmetric cones?

Comment: there was a complete classification by B.Vinberg. IMHO you need self-duality to get down to only 5 classes...

Comment: https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0138.43301